# Django template tag to return IP Address?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to write a simple Django template tag that will display the user's IP Address?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the information from the request (via the view function) in order to present it on a template.

You can't trivially write a custom tag since the IP address **must** come from the request.

Comment: I wanted to add this globally to all templates, but some views like /accounts/login/ from auth don't have a request object available.

Comment: @MikeN: Passing it using a context_processor is a better idea.

Comment: And that value is `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` :)

Answer (score 2):

you can also do this using context processors, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 0):

If you did it with javascript, you could just use this:

[jsonip.com](http://jsonip.com/)